# Can you call a filter hook by "add_action"?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I'd think you can't.
But I come across this code in a plugin's file:

```
add_action( 'render_block', array( $this, 'render_block' ), 5, 2 );
public function render_block( $block_content, $block ) {
.....
```

A brief search shows that `render_block` is a filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/

I put `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` inside the `render_block` function above and find out the invoker of this function is in line 309 of `class-wp-hook.php`, which is inside `apply_filter` function.

[image]

[image]

So I am little confused. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: Filters are hooks that expect a value to be returned. You could run the filter as an action, but the callback would still expect the passed value to be returned. Otherwise, PHP will throw out notices and your website may not function as expected. I can't think of any good reason why you would want to call a filter hook as an action hook - this would be awfully confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`add_action()` and `add_filter()` are the same function. If you look at [the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#source) you'll see that `add_action()` just calls `add_filter()`. So yes, this it is technically possible to register a filter callback with `add_action()`.

The difference between an action and a filter is that filters expect a return value, while actions do not. This is important when defining the hook with `do_action()` and `apply_filters()` because `do_action()` does not return a value. When it comes to registering a callback the only difference between `add_filter()` and `add_action()` is the name, but it's a good idea to use the right function so that it's clear what your code is doing. But if you make a mistake and use the wrong one, as this plugin has, it's not the end of the world.